# Does balanceTags() provide any escaping / protection?

Tags: validation, escaping

I'm just getting into WordPress and keep seeing sample code with balanceTags() used when echoing out a variable.

Am I right in thinking it does nothing in terms of output validation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so it will simply do its best to close any unclosed tag - that's it. Nothing more.

As you can see if you look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0), all the function does is make sure to balance out the tags that might not be. It's also explained in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/force_balance_tags). ("force_balance_tags" is the real function that does the work; "balanceTags" defers to it if the options or attributes ask it to)

Hope this helps!